# PyTorch Lightning (Trainable Params - Wrong)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am employing MULTI-GPU training using pytorch lightning. The below output displays the model:

```
GPU available: True, used: True
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0,1,2,3]
┏━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━┓
┃    ┃ Name       ┃ Type              ┃ Params ┃
┡━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━┩
│ 0  │ encoder    │ Encoder           │  2.0 M │
│ 1  │ classifier │ Sequential        │  8.8 K │
│ 2  │ criterion  │ BCEWithLogitsLoss │      0 │
│ 3  │ train_acc  │ Accuracy          │      0 │
│ 4  │ val_acc    │ Accuracy          │      0 │
│ 5  │ train_auc  │ AUROC             │      0 │
│ 6  │ val_auc    │ AUROC             │      0 │
│ 7  │ train_f1   │ F1Score           │      0 │
│ 8  │ val_f1     │ F1Score           │      0 │
│ 9  │ train_mcc  │ MatthewsCorrCoef  │      0 │
│ 10 │ val_mcc    │ MatthewsCorrCoef  │      0 │
│ 11 │ train_sens │ Recall            │      0 │
│ 12 │ val_sens   │ Recall            │      0 │
│ 13 │ train_spec │ Specificity       │      0 │
│ 14 │ val_spec   │ Specificity       │      0 │
└────┴────────────┴───────────────────┴────────┘
Trainable params: 2.0 M
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I have set Encoder to be untrainable using the below code:

```
ckpt = torch.load(chk_path)
self.encoder.load_state_dict(ckpt['state_dict'])
self.encoder.requires_grad = False
```

Shouldn't `trainable params` be `8.8 K` rather than `2.0 M` ?

My optimizer is the following:

```
optimizer =  torch.optim.RMSprop(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, self.parameters()), lr =self.lr, weight_decay = self.weight_decay)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.encoder.requires_grad = False` doesn't do anything; in fact, torch Modules don't have a `requires_grad` flag.

What you should do instead is use the `requires_grad_` method (note the second underscore), that will set `requires_grad` for all the parameters of this module to the desired value:

```
self.encoder.requires_grad_(False)
```

as described here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.requires_grad_

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `requires_grad=False` for all encoder parameters one-by-one:

```
for param in self.encoder.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if you execute the following piece of code:

```py
class MNISTModel(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.l1 = torch.nn.Linear(28 * 28, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.relu(self.l1(x.view(x.size(0), -1)))

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_nb):
        x, y = batch
        loss = F.cross_entropy(self(x), y)
        return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.02)

mnist_model = MNISTModel()
mnist_model.l2.requires_grad = False
print(mnist_model.l2.weight.requires_grad)
print(mnist_model.l2.bias.requires_grad)
ModelSummary(mnist_model)
```

You will get:

```bash
True
True

  | Name | Type   | Params
--------------------------------
0 | l1   | Linear | 1.2 M 
1 | l2   | Linear | 2.5 M 
2 | l3   | Linear | 15.7 K
--------------------------------
3.7 M     Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
3.7 M     Total params
14.827    Total estimated model params size (MB)
```

which means that this is actually not deactivating `requires_grad` for the parameters in that layer. So, you have two option according to (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#setting-requires-grad)

1. Applying `.requires_grad_()` to a module as suggested by @burzam (the more correct one)

```py
mnist_model = MNISTModel()
mnist_model.l2.requires_grad_(False)
ModelSummary(mnist_model)
```

```bash
  | Name | Type   | Params
--------------------------------
0 | l1   | Linear | 1.2 M 
1 | l2   | Linear | 2.5 M 
2 | l3   | Linear | 15.7 K
--------------------------------
1.2 M     Trainable params
2.5 M     Non-trainable params
3.7 M     Total params
14.827    Total estimated model params size (MB)
```

2. Loop through the parameters in the module

```py
mnist_model = MNISTModel()
for param in mnist_model.l2.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

ModelSummary(mnist_model)
```

you will see:

```bash
  | Name | Type   | Params
--------------------------------
0 | l1   | Linear | 1.2 M 
1 | l2   | Linear | 2.5 M 
2 | l3   | Linear | 15.7 K
--------------------------------
1.2 M     Trainable params
2.5 M     Non-trainable params
3.7 M     Total params
14.827    Total estimated model params size (MB)
```

You need to to set `requires_grad` to `False` for all the parameters in the specific layers you want to deactivate